# In PS ZVS FB Converter, when the primary current flows through the diode D3, why does diode D5 on the secondary side conduct?

Tags: full-bridge, zvs

I'm learning a PS ZVS FB Converter, the circuit is as fellow:
[image]

The waveform is as fellow. ip is the primary current of transformer.

[image]

During the time [t2,t3], the circuit works as fellow:
[image]

The thick solid line shows the path through which the current flows.

My question is that during the time [t2,t3], when the primary current flows through the diode D3, ***Vab = 0***, and the primary current is decreasing. Then according to ***uL=Ldi/dt***, the voltage across the primary side of transformer is negative. So shouldn't it be D5 off and D6 on? Why does D5 on and the voltage of the second side of transformer is zero?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Q2 and Q4 are both on during [t2, t3]. This means that the primary side of the transformer is shorted, so there are zero volts across it, and no current is flowing through the primary-side diodes (it's going through the MOSFETs instead). As a consequence, the secondary voltage is zero as well, and both D5 and D6 can conduct as the secondary-side smoothing inductor keeps pulling current from them. The primary-side current decreases as the transformer's leakage inductance is beginning to discharge slowly via the on-resistance of the MOSFETs and the primary winding resistance.

In reality, it's not all going to be perfect, so one diode might conduct a little more than the other. The differences will be small, though.